# How to compare to type of custom class

Tags: python

Say I have a custom class:

```
class MyClass():
    pass
```

and I want to test if this is an instance of MyClass. Can this be accomplished without the ugly mess of converting to a string?

```
str(type(MyClass())) == "<class '__main__.MyClass'>"
```

Comment: You mean like `isinstance(MyClass(), MyClass) #True`? Note: `type(MyClass()) == MyClass` also works but isn't recommended.

Comment: That's actually not true.

Comment: I was looking for an answer which resembled the above because it could also be used as `type(MyClass()) in [class1, class2]`.

Comment: You can still use as you can provide multiple types in the second argument, e.g. `isinstance(MyClass(), (MyClass, OtherClass)) == True`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can this be accomplished without the ugly mess of converting to a string?

Yes. Use the built-in function [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). From the docs:

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. If object is not an object of the given type, the function always returns false.

```
>>> class MyClass():
...     pass
... 
>>> isinstance(MyClass(), MyClass)
True
```

You could also do this using `type` this way:

```
...
>>> type(MyClass()) == MyClass
True
```

But this is not recommend because `type` fails to take subclasses into account. [From the documentation for `type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

> The `isinstance()` built-in function is recommended for testing the type of an object, because it takes subclasses into account.

Comment: Or... in this case... `not` recommended.

Comment: Yes, there are no problems with your post, that's why I upvoted it. :p

Answer (score 2):

Use `__class__.__name__` on the instance, like this:

```
>>> class MyClass():
...    pass
...
>>> i = MyClass()
>>> i.__class__.__name__
'MyClass'
```

Or, `isinstance` if you have access to the parent class:

```
>>> isinstance(i, MyClass)
True
```

As any object of a class is also an instance of any parent classes, `isinstance` will return `True` for all parents as well:

```
>>> class MyOtherClass(MyClass):
...    pass
...
>>> q = MyOtherClass()
>>> isinstance(q, MyClass)
True
>>> isinstance(q, MyOtherClass)
True
>>> isinstance(q, object)
True
```

However:

```
>>> q.__class__.__name__
'MyOtherClass'
```

Comment: OP wouldn't be able to create `i` without access to the class.